# Appcelerator / Titanium location of iOS simulator sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm posting this to assist users who will be encountering the same thing I did when trying to locate a sqlite database being used on the iOS simulator when using Appcelerator.

**xCode Version:** 8.3.x

**Appcelerator Studio:** 4.8.x / **SDK:** 6.x

**Issue/Test Case:** I need to test several iterations of loading data from the sqlite database to a remote mySQL server. I want to place an existing sqlite database file in the folder and have the simulator recognize this file so I can use it for testing/development.

**Question:** Where is the sqlite database stored on the iOS simulator, can I place an existing sqlite database in this folder and have my app recognize it?

**Answer:** Yes

**Steps to achieve:**
This is what I did to locate where the simulator/device is looking for

**1. Find out where your application is located in the filesystem by adding this code in your index.js (or another file of your choosing).**

`Ti.API.info("app directory: " + Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory);`

**This will give you the long filesystem directory location:**
/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96662E38-C659-4568-B53F-C32DC6B2B73D/data/Containers/Data/Application/96662E38-C659-4568-B53F-C32AB6B2C03D ***/Documents/***

**2. This was almost the correct location but the sqlite database is actually stored in the following location:**

/Users/[username]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96662E38-C659-4568-B53F-C32DC6B2B73D/data/Containers/Data/Application/96662E38-C659-4568-B53F-C32AB6B2C03D ***/Library/Private Documents/[filename].sql***

**3. You can use this location to put an existing sqlite database file and execute sql statements against it.**

**4. I'm sure you could reference another directory in your app but I was looking for the default storage directory since my app uses this location.**

Hope this helps someone, as I was looking for this specific functionality for testing/development.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get the database included is to simply add it to the resources folder, or a sub folder in the resources directory. Then you simply call the Ti.Database.install() method. This will copy the database into the simulator location you found. The upside with this method is that you don't have find the location for each iOS simulator (i.e. iPhone 5, 6, 6 plus, 7...).

I do use your method when I need to query the database externally with SQLite manager or another such program.

You can read more here http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database